# When are authors on publications in Google Scholar clickable

Tags: publications, google-scholar, online-publication

Whenever one searches for publications on Google Scholar, some of the authors of some publications are clickable (underlined / hyperlinked), but others aren't.

What determines this behavior? Is there a way to manage this as an author?

I have a few publications that are in my profile, but I am not clickable as an author in some of them when searching for the publication.

Comment: Have you checked if you have set your profile to public? (The gist of Brian Borcher's answer)

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Yes, it's marked as public

Comment: OK, I can confirm that your profile is public, while your name is not clickable. For long has your profile been public?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper It has been from the start (half a year ago)

Comment: After such a long time, I would call that a bug. One idea is to set your profile to non-public, then to public again and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

In order to get a clickable link in an author's name in Google Scholar results, three main conditions must be met:

1. The author must have created a public profile in Google Scholar.
2. The profile must be verified with an academic email account.
3. The profile must be up to date (only documents that have been added to the profile will appear with a link to the author profile in a Google Scholar page of results).

If these conditions are met and still the link does not appear, the cause might be that Google Scholar is not able to match the name of the author in the profile, to one name in the list of authors of the documents (the names might be just different enough). But I don't remember seeing cases of this.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Some authors have published their Google Scholar profiles and other authors have not.  If you click on an author's name and the author has a profile, then you'll see that author's profile information.

You might think that Google Scholar would show you the list of all publications by authors with that same name, but there are so many name duplications that this isn't done.

If you have a public author profile, then it should be possible for anyone who accesses one of your publications to click on your name and get to that public profile.

Comment: This answer contradicts the question.  Is the question wrong?  Is Scholar buggy?

Comment: I've described how Google Scholar works in my experience and how it is supposed to work.  I've never seen any situation in which it doesn't work as described.  Therefore, I  assume that the OP either doesn't have a public profile or is confused.      There's really no way to confirm this report without detailed information (i.e. the name of the OP.)  If the OP would send me a message directly, I'd be happy to check what's happening.

Comment: At least at the moment, only one of the two papers in Xander's profile links to the profile.  The other paper is in the profile, but there's no link from the paper to the profile.

Comment: My colleague also has the same problem.  His profile can only be reached via mine, but it will never appear on Google search result, and if his papers appear, his name is not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is there is a major bug with Google Scholar that just doesn't pick up some names; yes of course I am one such academic, but if you search you will find numerous examples.
So unclickable names may be because the authors profile is not set to public, or the simple bug described below.

Naturally other answers will all be about making it public etc etc, but in fact, after many hours of investigation, there seems to also be a simple bug that no one has a solution to.  Of course I have reported this to Google with out response.  It seems to be because whatever you do some names are **not indexed**; so the profile exists, but is just not linked.
Try mine for example; search for my name you find my papers, but no indexed (clickable) name and no profile. One can only find this with a direct link, which one can of course put on your website etc
[RBJ profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=LMnR82wAAAAJ&hl=en).
Another example is here [Another example](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/53989406/public-google-scholar-profile-not-findable-as-a-profile?hl=en), but there are many.
The reason for entering this as an answer, rather than a comment is that there are many academics, and authorities that judge academics by their Google metrics and simply do not understand that these unfixable bugs exist.  "S/he can't be a reputable academic because doesn't even have a Google Scholar Profile". Metrics are never a great way to assess one another anyway, but it is essential that everyone recognises Google Scholar is buggy and unreliable.
Please don't anyone respond with "click make it public".  Obviously we have all done this. I am astonished that people assume, despite evidence and people's experience to the contrary, that this is the one computer system that has been invented without bugs.
[screen shot of the public tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnvZl.jpg)